# Using special characters such as '+' in a DTD entity

Tags: xml, dtd

I'm trying to define an entity whose value contains a '+' character, but if I do so, I get a weird error message further down the line.  If I remove the + character, everything works fine.  I can't seem to figure out a way to escape it.
I get the error not only with the library I'm currently using, but also with the online validator at http://www.validome.org/grammar/validate/
A short sample :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!ENTITY % Foo "BAR"> <!--No problem here-->
<!ENTITY % Baz "QUUX+QUUUX"> <!--This will cause trouble later on-->

<!ENTITY % FooBazType "( %Foo; | %Baz; )">

<!ELEMENT tagName EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST tagName attributeName %FooBazType; #REQUIRED> <!--Here, you get the error message : The enumerated type list must end with ')' in the "attributeName" attribute declaration.-->
```

Does anyone know of a way to get a + character (or something that'll also correctly validate an XML document that would contain a + character in that location) in there somehow?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: That symbol is valid, does it think it's trying to reference a Unicode character?

Comment: Not as far as I know, I tried using numeric escape sequence (&#43;) but that didn't work either.  Further research did bring up the concept NMTOKEN (http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-Nmtoken), and that does seem to exclude plus...  Though I can't believe I'm the first person to run into this issue, as the + character can't be that uncommon?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with '$' char (hex = 0x24)

Comment: @Marek: my answer applies to the '$' character too. You cannot use it in enumerated attribute values.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the entity itself, but the fact that it is used to define an attribute where the [legal values are enumerated](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-Enumeration). Such values must match `Nmtoken` (one or more `NameChar`s). That excludes '+' and '$', which are not part of [the definition of `NameChar`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-NameChar). The example below illustrates this.

plus.dtd:

```
<!ELEMENT tagName EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST tagName 
          attributeName (BAR | FOO+BAZ) #REQUIRED>
```

plus.xml:

```
<tagName attributeName="FOO+BAZ"/>
```

xmllint output when trying to validate plus.xml against plus.dtd:

```
xmllint --dtdvalid plus.dtd plus.xml 
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<tagName attributeName="FOO+BAZ"/>
plus.dtd:2: parser error : ')' required to finish ATTLIST enumeration
<!ATTLIST tagName attributeName (BAR | FOO+BAZ) #REQUIRED>
                                          ^
plus.dtd:2: parser error : Space required after the attribute type
<!ATTLIST tagName attributeName (BAR | FOO+BAZ) #REQUIRED>
                                          ^
plus.dtd:2: parser error : Content error in the external subset
<!ATTLIST tagName attributeName (BAR | FOO+BAZ) #REQUIRED>
                                          ^
Could not parse DTD plus.dtd
```

---

Using '+' or '$' in a fixed attribute value is OK.

plus2.dtd:

```
<!ELEMENT tagName EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST tagName 
          attributeName CDATA #FIXED "FOO+$BAZ">
```

xmllint output (no error):

```
xmllint --dtdvalid plus2.dtd plus.xml 
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<tagName attributeName="FOO+$BAZ"/>
```